# How to interpret the word "straddle" in this context

Tags: meaning

The text is:

"As infrastructure money flows, Mitch Landrieu must straddle partisan divide"

I can't figure out staddle in it, what does it means in this text?

Answer (score 2):

straddle only has one basic meaning: to have your legs on either side of something.

- straddle a fence
- straddle a horse

partisan divide in AmE means: the divide between Democrats and Republicans

If you straddle a divide, you have one foot [or leg] in either camp.

When you ride a horse, you sit on its back and have one leg on either side of it. That's is straddling horse. [AKA sitting astride]